# is there something like a webhook on firebase so that I can increment/decrement presence

Tags: firebase

I need to sync the number of online users in each chat room to my elastic search repository (the one that searches for rooms).

Is there a way to attach a webhook server-side onto the connect and disconnect events that fire in firebase so that I can inc and decrement the user counts in my elastic search records?

Comment: Did you consider using a node.js client for this? The operation might be a bit lightweight to warrant that, but it would at least allow you to implement it with the current JavaScript SDK.

Comment: so is the idea be to create single node.js client that subscribes to the members path and set listners on child_added and child_removed?    Does the client keep only a single socket connection open for this?  I'm assuming that I can get something like ref_item.parent so that I can know what room they were leaving/entering if the path was like `members/room1/bob`

Comment: Your node.js client would simply listen for the same events as usual. It will indeed keep a connection open.

Comment: For example, see [Flashlight](https://github.com/firebase/flashlight), an example app that syncs Firebase to ElasticSearch, and also answers ES queries by "queueing" them through Firebase, so you don't need a RESTful service or direct access to ES.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would probably use a node.js client for this. That way you can write your client against the same JavaScript SDK that you're already using.

In that client you would subscribe to the same events on the same paths as you would do in a regular front-end client. But instead of updating the UI, you'd just update a node in Firebase itself.

So a regular Firebase client would:

- accept user input and send it to Firebase
- listen for changes in Firebase an update the user's screen

This node.js client would instead:

- listen for changes in Firebase and update the data in Firebase based on that

As Kato mentions: [Flashlight](https://github.com/firebase/flashlight) is a perfect example of such an application, synchronizing data from Firebase to ElasticSearch and fielding ES queries by queueing them through Firebase.